# Ubuntu 14.04 to Windows *CANT BOOT INTO WINDOWS AT ALL

Tags: boot, windows-7

I've recently been stuck on ubuntu for a while now. I tried formatting and removing the partions but the only error i got was BOOTMGR was missing... Could someone give me some help?

Comment: Hi, if you want to use Linux, try Lubuntu because lxde is really a light weight, I have 8GB RAM but I only use lxde and don't use Unity. 1GB is really low to run Unity. And if you use Windows XP is better unless you increase your RAM. Windows 7 will consume a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Linux, try Lubuntu because lxde is really a light weight, I have 8GB RAM but I only use lxde and don't use Unity. 1GB is really low to run Unity. And if you use Windows XP is better unless you increase your RAM. Windows 7 will consume a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following steps as I use this and it fix the problem.

1) Insert Windows 7 CD or make your USB bootable with Windows 7.
2) On the first page, just click Install.
3) And then, click Repair your computer. (this option is on the below part)
4) Click Next on the prompted message and then choose command prompt. 
5) In the command prompt, type following command
**bootrec /RebuildBcd**
**bootrec /FixMbr**
**bootrec /FixBoot**
6) Reboot your pc.
7) Done.

*The idea is you have to choose command prompt when you choose "Repair your computer" and type the command given above.

Please tell me the result.. =)